# Live Data, Repository gets called multiple time android

Tags: android, repository, viewmodel, android-livedata

I am working on Google's new `Android Architecture Component` **AAC**

**My problem**

method inside `ViewModel` class gets called multiple time , causing error

**1** getLoggedInUser() gets called multiple times

**2** Before retrofit's onNext() or onError() , the **onChanged()** gets called

**MyActivity**

```
LoginPojo loginPojo=new LoginPojo();
            loginPojo.setEmailId(viewFunctions.getText(etLoginEmailId));
            loginPojo.setPassword(viewFunctions.getText(etLoginPwd));
            viewModel.loginUser(loginPojo);

            viewModel.getLoggedInUser().observe(this, new Observer<LoginPojo>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable LoginPojo pojo) {
            viewFunctions.hideCustomProgress();
            if (pojo.isError()) {

                if (pojo.isNetworkError()) {

                } else {

                }


            } else {

                if (pojo.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(constants.ERROR)) {

                } else {

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

**ViewModel**

```
private MutableLiveData<LoginPojo> mutableLogin = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public final LiveData<LoginPojo> loginData = Transformations.switchMap(mutableLogin, new Function<LoginPojo, LiveData<LoginPojo>>() {
        @Override
        public LiveData<LoginPojo> apply(LoginPojo input) {
            return repository.loginUser(input.getEmailId(), input.getPassword());
        }
    });


public void loginUser(LoginPojo loginPojo) {

         mutableLogin.setValue(loginPojo);

    }


    public LiveData<LoginPojo> getLoggedInUser() {

        return loginData;
    }
```

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same. Did u found any solution ?

Comment: I had problems with the Transformations.switchMap . That was creating the problem . Refer Google documentation for simple use of Repository call in viewmodel .

Comment: what was your final solution?